# Error returning an Object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have an Array of Objects called ENTITIES and the following function that receives and String id and the whole objects Array:

> function getEntityById( id, ENTITIES) {
>         id = id.toString(); //made sure id is string
>
> > ENTITIES.forEach(function( ENT ) {
> >
> > > ```
> > >   if( ENT.name == id ) {
> > > ```
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >     return( ENT );
> > > >   }
> > > > ```
> > > >
> > > > });
> > > >            }

I've already checked the function with console.log and its working fine. (id is checked and the 'if' is getting TRUE). The problem occurs when i try to access the returned Object 'ENT' outside the function, like this:

> var entity0 = getEntityById( 'test', ENTITIES);
>   console.log( entity0.id );

I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined 
It's like getEntityById function never really returned an Object.

Could you guys help me? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this function:

```
function getEntityById( id, ENTITIES) { 
  id = id.toString(); //made sure id is string
  ENTITIES.forEach(
```

and then you have this function

```
    function( ENT ) {
      if( ENT.name == id ) {
      return( ENT );
    }
```

which returns back to your original function:

```
  }); 
}
```

which doesn't do anything with it, so `getEntityById` returns nothing... so you get undefined.

What you could do is:

```
function getEntityById( id, ENTITIES) { 
  id = id.toString(); //made sure id is string
  var return_ENT;
  ENTITIES.forEach(function( ENT ) {
    if( ENT.name == id ) {
      return_ENT = ENT;
    }
  }); 
  return return_ENT;
 }
```

A better option might be to use filter:

```
function getEntityById( id, ENTITIES) { 
  id = id.toString(); //made sure id is string
  return ENTITIES.filter(function(ent) { return ent.name == id})[0];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the found entity you have to save it, exit the `forEach` loop and return the variable:

```
function getEntityById(id, ENTITIES) {
    var result = null;
    id = id.toString(); //made sure id is string
    ENTITIES.forEach(function( ENT ) {
        if( ENT.name == id ) {
            result = ENT;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

But in that case you'll do some redundant work (if the required entity is found - there's no need to continue the loop). So I would recommend to do like:

```
function getEntityById(id, ENTITIES) {
    var i = ENTITIES.length;
    while(--i >= 0) {
        if (ENTITIES[i].id === id) {
            return ENTITIES[i];
        }
    }
}
```